# How to scheduling jobs created in different scheduler instance

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using spring-boot-starter-quartz 2.2.1.RELEASE to schedule Quartz jobs.And I've deploy my code on two nodes.
And the quartz.properties is like this:

For node one:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: machine1
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
```

For node two:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: machine2
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
```

So in this situation, each node can run the same scanning job separately.
And now in my database in "qrtz_job_details", I can have two job records ,namely scanJobbyMachine1 and scanJobbyMachine2.

I also deployed an frontend UI on node1 that have RESTful API to schedule jobs. And I use nginx to randomly send my request to one of my nodes.

If I made a request to query all jobs, the request may be sent to node1 and only node1's job will be shown. But I want to show both node1 and node2's jobs.

If I made a request to update scanJobbyMachine1, and it may be sent to node2. And update can't be made, because node2 only have properties file whose instanceName is machine2.

Here is my plan:

Plan A:use cluster mode. But Quartz doesn't support "Allow Job Excution to be pin to a cluster node" yet. So in cluster mode, my job will only be excuted by one node. But I want both node to do the scanning jobs.
[here is the issue link in github](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/344)

Plan B:use Non cluster mode. Then I have to write duplicate APIs in Controller like this:

```
localhost:8090/machine0/updateJob
localhost:8090/machine1/updateJob
```

And use nginx to set when I request /machine0/updateJob, send it to 10.110.200.60(machine1's ip), when I request /machine1/updateJob, send it to 10.110.200.62(machine2's ip)

And for queryAllJobs I have to use my backend to send request to 10.110.200.60 and 10.110.200.62 first, and combine the response list in my backend, then show it in the frontend.

Plan C:write another backend with two properties files. just to schedule the jobs and don't excute these jobs (I don't know if this can work) and depoyed it on these two nodes.

I really don't want write and deploy another backend like Plan C or write duplicate APIs like Plan B.
Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is a cluster problem :)

Perhaps you could dynamically configure your job registration: as node1 start, it will be alone on the cluster and run jobs only on this one. As node2 start, the two nodes can be called.